# Binding two queries in the same chart

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0

I have this query:

```
public static string shitjeJavore = "with java  as " 
  +" (select subscription.username as username, " 
  +"convert(varchar,max(subscription.saledate),101)as saledate, " 
  +" convert(varchar,convert(datetime,max(startdate),100)) as startdate, " 
  +" convert(varchar,convert(datetime,max(enddate),100)) as enddate from subscription  " 
  +" inner join SaleReport on SaleReport.username=subscription.username " 
  +" inner join login on  login.username=subscription.username " 
  +" inner join users on users.username=subscription.name " 
  +" where pkgid = '5'  " 
  +" and subscription.saledate >=(@from) 
      and subscription.saledate <= DATEADD(week,1,@from) " 
  +" and login.version> CONVERT(float,'1.70') " 
  +" and login.lockaccount='false' " 
  +" and users.Role<>'admin' " 
  + " group by subscription.username " 
  +" having GETDATE()>=max(subscription.saledate)) " 
  +" , abonim as ( select count(username)as cc ,username  from SaleReport " 
  +" group by username ) " 
  +" select max(saledate) as saledate,count(java.username) as usernameCount " 
  +" from java inner join abonim on java.username=abonim.username " 
  +" where cc=1 " 
  +" group by (saledate) " +
```

And i want to bind it twice at the same chart. In one series i want the previous query to be bind, in the second series the only difference would be in the WHERE condition:

so instead of:

> where cc=1
>   i want it to be 
>   where cc>1

is this possible with the .NET Chart component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to combine the data in different views in order to create them as columns of the same result as follows:

```
  with java  as 
(select subscription.username as username,
convert(varchar,max(subscription.saledate),101)as saledate, 
convert(varchar,convert(datetime,max(startdate),100)) as startdate, 
convert(varchar,convert(datetime,max(enddate),100)) as enddate from subscription  
inner join SaleReport on SaleReport.username=subscription.username
inner join login on  login.username=subscription.username
inner join users on users.username=subscription.name 
where pkgid = '5'  
and subscription.saledate >=('02/01/2014') and subscription.saledate <= DATEADD(week,1,'02/01/2014') 
and login.version> CONVERT(float,'1.70') 
and login.lockaccount='false'
and users.Role<>'admin'
 group by subscription.username 
having GETDATE()>=max(subscription.saledate)
)
, abonim as ( select count(username)as cc ,username  from SaleReport 
group by username ),
Riabonim as
(select java.username, count(java.username) as cc
from java inner join abonim on java.username=abonim.username
where cc>1
group by java.username) ,
NewSub as
(select java.username, count(java.username) as cc
from java inner join abonim on java.username=abonim.username
where cc=1
group by java.username)
select (java.saledate) as saledate,
count(Riabonim.cc) as RiabonimCounter,
count(NewSub.cc) as NewCounter
from java
full outer join Riabonim on java.username=  Riabonim.username
full outer join NewSub on java.username= NewSub.username
group by saledate
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two different series for your chart. Please look at this, it'll be helpfull :
[Blogs MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx)